# Publish a Doc Add-on from a library

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been developing an Add-on that performs calculation in Google Doc.  During development I have everything in an App-script library and a test Google Doc that attaches the library through Resources->Library.  I now want to publish it as an Add-on for Marketplace.

I have several problems first, the icon doesn't show up in card sidebar, see appscript.json below "logoUrl". How do I properly code this to display a png file from my Google drive?

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "CalcPad",
      "logoUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZFzKwFj55eR8aTD1A72E_f5s3ew-xSZH/view?usp=sharing",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "enabled": true,
        "runFunction": "calcPadOnOpen"
      },
      "universalActions": [{
        "label": "Side Bar",
        "runFunction": "showSideBar"
      }, {
        "label": "Calculate",
        "runFunction": "calculate"
      }]
    },
    "docs": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "enabled": true,
        "runFunction": "showSideBar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second I publish from manifest but get no Add-on menu Items. How do I get Add-on menu items? They are supposed to come from calcPadOnOpen.

If I click the card I get the following error message.

[image: Error message]

CPObject is in the library, as is showSideBar and calculate.  And how does object CPPreprocessor even get called?  Its called from calculate.

Also my sidebar uses HTML Service and google.script.run to communicate with the server.  During development I had to create a wrapper in the Google Doc script file to access the methods in CalcPad, such as:

```
function showSideBar() {
  try {
    return CalcPad.showSiddeBar();
  }
  catch(err) {
    throw "\Error in CalcPad.showSideBar: "+err;
  }
};
```

How do I properly code these calls in the Add-on library, or modify the manifest to link to the library.  So google.script.run call from library can access the Doc paragraphs to modify from my side bar rather than a wrapper in Goggle Doc script?